# Is the degree homomorphism $\text{deg}: \text{Pic}(X)\to \mathbb{Z}$ surjective?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, algebraic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field, $X$ a curve over $k$, $\operatorname{Div}(X)$ the divisor group of $X$, and $\operatorname{Pic}(X)$ the divisor class group (the Picard group) of $X$.
Consider the degree homomorphism
$$
\begin{split}
\deg: \operatorname{Div}(X)&\to\mathbb{Z} \\
\sum_{P\in X}n_{P}P &\mapsto \sum_{P\in X}n_{P}\cdot [k(P):k],
\end{split}
$$
and the induced degree homomorphism
$$
\deg: \operatorname{Pic}(X)\to\mathbb{Z}.
$$
Here $n_{p}\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $k(P)$ is the residue field of $P$.
**Are those homomorphisms surjective?** 
Namely, is there necessarily exists a divisor $D\in\operatorname{Div}(X)$, with $\deg(D)=1$ ?

Comment: Any restrictions on $k$ or $X$?

Comment: Not always. For instance, if $X$ is a conic with $X(k) = \varnothing$, the image of $\deg$ is $2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: For smooth affine curves: $(x,y,z)\in \overline{\Bbb{F}}_3, x^2+y^2=0,xz-1=0$ then $x/y\in \Bbb{F}_9$ so $2\ | \ [\Bbb{F}_3(x,y,z):\Bbb{F}_3]$

Comment: @Sasha that looks like an answer to me. Would you care to record it as such below?

Comment: Gut feeling: this should hold for $k$ algebraically closed and generic $X$ I think.

Comment: Yes, I also think that for $k$ algebraically closed this is true. Since in that case $[k(P):k]=1$ for every $P\in X$, considering a simple divisor $D=P$ (for any $P\in X$), will give $\text{deg}(D)=1$. My question was for a generic $k$, and I got an answer from @Sasha, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not always. For instance, if $X$ is a conic with $X(k)=\varnothing$, the image of $\deg$ is $2\mathbb{Z}$.