# Surjectivity of the degree homomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Regarding the following question and discussion:

[Is the degree homomorphism $\text{deg}: \text{Pic}(X)\to \mathbb{Z}$ surjective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3873938/is-the-degree-homomorphism-textdeg-textpicx-to-mathbbz-surjective)

We agree that if $X$ is a curve over an **algebraically** closed field the answer is yes, and not allways otherwise.
What is the answer in the case that $X$ is a curve over a **separably** closed field?

Is this a sufficient condition for the degree homomorphism to be surjective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, assuming you take "curve" to mean "geometrically reduced". Every geometrically reduced $k$-scheme of finite type has a $k^s$ point by proposition 3.2.20 of Liu's *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves* (the idea of the proof is that geometrically reduced means $k(X)/k$ is separable, and the locus of such behavior is open for schemes of finite type over a field). This proves your claim, assuming you take geometrically reduced as part of your definition of a curve: pick a regular $k^s$ point.

You may also consult [Stacks 04QM](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04QM) for details on the statement above.